# Split string using more than one char as delimeter

Tags: c, string, split

Let's say I have a string `"file1.h: file2.c,file3.cpp"` and I want to split it into `"file1.h"` and `"file2.c,file3.cpp"` - that is using `:` (`:` and whitespace) as delimiter. How can I do it?

I tried this code with no help:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char str[] = "file1.h: file2.c,file3.cpp";
   char name[100];
   char depends[100];
   sscanf(str, "%s: %s", name, depends);
   printf("Name: %s\n", name);
   printf("Deps: %s\n", depends);
}
```

And the output I get is:

> Name: file1.h:
>
> Deps:

Comment: You might want to check the return value of `sscanf()`, and consider whether `"%s"` *really* doesn't match `':'` , as you seem to assume.

Comment: `: and backspace`.. are you sure?

Comment: if it is `:` and ` ` (space), why don't you try `strtok()`? it accepts more that once delimiter at a time, FWIW.

Comment: I tried strtok as well, but that I get a space in the beginning of the second string (depends)

Comment: Why are there 2 different delimiters? Do they have the same meaning? If not you should plit the string in two first, and then split the other part. It appears that it's something like a definition, *file.h* being the "*key*" and the value being a list of files. If that's the case then you should use a parsing technique and a data structure that clearly express that.

Comment: `sscanf(str, "%99[^:]: %99[^\n]", name, depends);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to need is `strtok()`. Read about it in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). Related quote from `C11`, chapter §7.24.5.8

> A sequence of calls to the `strtok` function breaks the string pointed to by `s1` into a
>   sequence of tokens, **each of which is delimited by a character from the string pointed to
>   by `s2`**. [...]

In your case, you can use a delimiter like

```
  char * delim = ": "; //combination of : and a space
```

go get the job done.

Things to mention additionally,

- the input needs to be modifiable (which is, in your case) for `strtok()`
- and it actually destroys the input fed to it, keep a copy around if you need the actual later.

Comment: Note that `strtok()` has a lot of problems. I recommend `strpbrk()` instead. It's not reentrant, not thread safe, it's designed in a way that is confusing, passing `NULL` after the first time, etc. It modifies the input string. It sucks.

Answer (score 1):

As Sourav says, you really need to use `strtok` for tokenizing strings. But this doesn't explain *why* your existing code is not working.

The answer lies in the specification for `sscanf` and how it handles a `'%s'` in the format string.

From the `man` page:

> s      Matches  a  sequence  of  non-white-space  characters;

So, the presence of a colon-space in your format string is largely irrelevant for mathcing the first `'%s'`. When `sscanf` sees the first `%s` it simply consumes the input string until a whitespace character is encountered, giving you your value for `name` of `"file1.h:"` (note the inclusion of the colon).

Next it tries to deal with the colon-space sequence in your format string.

Again, from the `man` page

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives  which  describe        how  to  process  the sequence of input characters.

The colon-space sequence does not match any known directive (i.e. "%" followed by something) and thus you get a matching failure.

If, instead, your format string was simply `"%s%s"`, then `sscanf` will get you almost exactly what you want.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char str[] = "file1.h: file2.c,file3.cpp";
   char name[100];
   char depends[100];
   sscanf(str, "%s%s", name, depends);
   printf("str: '%s'\n", str);
   printf("Name: %s\n", name);
   printf("Deps: %s\n", depends);
   return 0;
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
str: 'file1.h: file2.c,file3.cpp'
Name: file1.h:
Deps: file2.c,file3.cpp
```

At this point, you can simply check that `sscanf` gave a return value of 2 (i.e. it found two values), and that the last character of `name` is a colon. Then just truncate `name` and you have your answer.

Of course, by this logic, you aren't going to be able to use `sscanf` to parse your `depends` variable into multiple strings ... which is why others are recommending using `strtok`, `strpbrk` etc because you are both parsing and tokenizing your input.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way to do it, it uses `strchr()`, but this assumes that the input string always has the format

```
name: item1,item2,item3,...,itemN
```

Here is the program

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    const char *const string = "file1.h: file2.c,file3.cpp ";

    const char *head;
    const char *tail;
    const char *next;

    // This basically makes a pointer to the `:'
    head = string;  
    // If there is no `:' this string does not follow
    // the assumption that the format is
    //
    //    name: item1,item2,item3,...,itemN
    //    
    if ((tail = strchr(head, ':')) == NULL)
        return -1;
    // Save a pointer to the next character after the `:'
    next = tail + 1;
    // Strip leading spaces
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *head) != 0)
        ++head;
    // Strip trailing spaces
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *(tail - 1)) != 0)
        --tail;     

    fputc('*', stdout);
    // Simply print the characters between `head' and `tail'
    // you could as well copy them, or whatever
    fwrite(head, 1, tail - head, stdout);
    fputc('*', stdout);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    head = next;
    while (head != NULL) {      
        tail = strchr(head, ',');
        if (tail == NULL) {
            // This means there are no more `,'
            // so we now try to point to the end
            // of the string
            tail = strchr(head, '\0');
        }
        // This is basically the same algorithm
        // just with a different delimiter which
        // will presumably be the same from
        // here
        next = tail + 1;
        // Strip leading spaces
        while (isspace((unsigned char) *head) != 0)
            ++head;
        // Strip trailing spaces
        while (isspace((unsigned char) *(tail - 1)) != 0)
            --tail;     
        // Here is where you can extract the string
        // I print it surrounded by `*' to show that
        // it's stripping white spaces
        fputc('*', stdout);
        fwrite(head, 1, tail - head, stdout);
        fputc('*', stdout);
        fputc('\n', stdout);
        // Try to point to the next one
        // or make head `NULL' if this is
        // the end of the string
        //
        // Note that the original `tail' pointer
        // that was pointing to the next `,' or
        // the end of the string, has changed but
        // we have saved it's original value
        // plus one, we now inspect what was
        // there
        if (*(next - 1) == '\0') {
            head = NULL;
        } else {
            head = next;
        }
    }
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    return 0;
}
```

It's excessively commented to guide the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am pretty late. I do not have much knowledge on inbuilt functions in C. So I started writing a solution for you. I don't think you need this now. But, anyway [here it is](https://github.com/iamparnab/code/blob/master/split_into_array.c) and modify it as per your need. If you find any bug feel free to tell.